# If $x_n \to x$ weakly then $\exists y_n \in \operatorname{co}\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ s.t. $y_n \to x$.

Tags: functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces, weak-topology

Let $X$ be a normed space and $x_n \to x$ [weakly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#Weak_convergence). I can [show that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648162/letting-x-n-to-x-weakly-in-a-normed-vector-space-x-prove-the-following-stat) there exists $\{y_n\} \subseteq \operatorname{co}\{x_1, x_2, \dots \}$ s.t. $\|y_n -x \| \to 0$ where co is [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). To show the existence of sequence, I used the following theorem

> 1.4. Theorem. If $\mathscr{X}$ is $a$ LCS and $A$ is a convex subset of $\mathscr{X}$, then $\mathrm{cl} A=\mathrm{wk}-\mathrm{cl} A$.

But I used $x\in \operatorname{wk-cl}(\{x_1, x_2, \dots \})\subseteq \operatorname{wk-cl}(\operatorname{co}\{x_1, x_2, \dots \})=\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{co}\{x_1, x_2, \dots\})$ but I can't show $y_n \in \operatorname{co}\{x_1, x_2, \dots x_n\}$. I know that there exists a sequence, perhaps I need to show that each $y_n$ lies in the convex hull of finite number of $x_n$'s. Please give me some ideas.

Comment: Convex hull of $(x_n)$ is equal to the set of all **finite** convex combinations of $x_n$'s.

Comment: @geetha290krn Then how to show $x\in \operatorname{wk-cl}  \left ( \operatorname{co} \{x_1,  \dots, x_n \} \right )$?

Comment: If you want a sequence demanded in the title, take the sequence $(y_n)$, as in your first sentence, then make a new sequence, by repeating $x_1$, then repeating $y_1$, then repeating $y_2$, and so on, in such a way as to get what you want.

Comment: @DavidMitra You are right. I typed it out with some details, but it is your idea. I think you can post an answer.

Comment: @geetha290krm Please feel free to post your write up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $y_n \in co \{x_1,x_2,...,x_{k_n}\}$ with $k_1<k_2<....$ Consider a sequence of the type $\{x_1,x_1,...,x_1, y_1,y_1,...,y_{1},y_2,y_2,...,....$ where you have blocks of size $k_1-1,k_2-1,...$. This satisfies your requirements.

Thanks to David Mitra for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you prove your supposition? How do we know that $y_n$ is in convex hull of finite number of elements?

Comment: @HashNuke The collection of all **finite** convex combinations of $x_1,x_2,...$ is a  convex set contaitning each $x_i$ so it must contain $co(x_1,x_2,...)$

Comment: I think I get what you mean.